Errors with regards to a <details> component in Docusaurus site after installing MUI
I'm working on a Docusaurus site, and I wanted to use a card component from MUI. However after I installed it, there are other pages where the <details> components have stopped working with the following error:
 Error: Can't render static file for pathname "/xxx/yyy/zzz"
            at generateStaticFile (/Users/rickkeenan/code/docs/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/ssg.js:119:15)
            at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
            at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:449:9)
            at async /Users/rickkeenan/code/docs/node_modules/p-map/index.js:57:22 {
          [cause]: Error: Expected component `Details` to be defined: you likely forgot to import, pass, or provide it.
              at _missingMdxReference (server.bundle.js:214586:9)
              at _createMdxContent (server.bundle.js:214365:17)
              at MDXContent (server.bundle.js:214583:8)
              at Uc (server.bundle.js:256799:44)
              at Xc (server.bundle.js:256801:253)
              at Z (server.bundle.js:256807:89)
              at Xc (server.bundle.js:256805:231)
              at Z (server.bundle.js:256807:89)
              at Xc (server.bundle.js:256801:481)
              at Z (server.bundle.js:256807:89)

Can anyone help? I have tried reading the Docusaurus Docs but cannot resolve it.

can you provide code sample of page where error occurs?
